# Android Studio Не запускается телефон эмулятора (AMD)

Tags: android, эмулятор, amd, avd

Установил Android Studio запускаю чистый шаблон. "System image" выбрал из "Other images" arm64-8va так как у меня процессор AMD. Сам виртуальный девайс создан с параметрами по умолчанию. Он запускается и просто висит с чернм экраном, на кнопки не реагирует. Когда-то начинает минут по 20 показывать надпись Android, иногода даже запускаетс но зависает на окне типа "Приложение не отвечает: Закрыть, Подождать" и так же не отвечает на любые нажатия. 
Бывают ошибки типа:

```
The ADB binary found at :C\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\platform-tools\ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problem
Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(393, 119), size=(272x21), dirty=(272x21 0, 0) (Присоединенное к системе устройство не работает.) ((null):0, (null))
```